# PHP & Parsing a JSON response

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to play with a web service via REST.

I finally am getting the results I want (or at least I think I am), but am unaware what to do with it. The response format is JSON.. I try outputting it via json_decode() to get it as an array, then I could do something with it.

You can see that I am getting "something" as a response as I am echoing the url that I am CURL'ing

I know this is a matter of education, but this is my first jaunt at this, so any help is appreciated. Again, my end goal is to obviously output the data in a readable format.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['word']))
    {
        $result= get_response_json($_GET['word']);
    } else {$result = "";}

    function get_response_json($word)
    {
        $postURL = "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=".urlencode($word);
        echo $postURL;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

?>

<html>
    <title>Test Rhyme</title>  
<body>

    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
        <input type="input" name="word" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="results">
        <?php
            print_r(json_decode($result, true));
        ?>
    </div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php. The one noteworthy thing I saw was this:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Note that there is a great example if you search for "curl_get(".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "ID": "1001",
        "Phone": "5555555555"
    }
]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json);

foreach($jsonArray as $value){
    $id = $value->ID;
    $phone = $value->Phone;
}
```

Comment: oh really? because I just pulled this from my site which is using it, perhaps in my obfuscating the information I messed something up, care to point it out?

Comment: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d31ce.php - find it for yourself if you'Re programmer

Comment: oh, yeah... the quote marks aren't escaped in my example, I usually load the contents of this JSON remotely, so don't have to deal with it. I'll update the example.

Comment: Well, it does, but for the example of this post, I included a snippet of my JSON as if it existed in the same file and made a simple syntax mistake :)

Comment: @genesisφ let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2603/discussion-between-patrick-robert-shea-oconnor-and-genesis-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified way to do it without cURL

```
function get_response_json($word)
    {
        $postURL = "http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getRhymes&word=".urlencode($word);
        $json = file_get_contents($postURL);
        return $json;
    }
```