# PHP JSON parse response

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using loop I want to get the following paramatersid,device_id from the given code

```
$str = '{"response":{"success":true,"result":{"success":[{"id":"31281985","device_id":"26965","message":"BIG WINTER CLOSING SALE! Starting from FRIDAY 30th Dec 2016. Discount upto 55%OFF on all Ladies, Gents & Kids Shoes. at All Branches of ENGLISH SHOES MULTAN. ","status":"pending","send_at":1485859669,"queued_at":0,"sent_at":0,"delivered_at":0,"expires_at":1485863269,"canceled_at":0,"failed_at":0,"received_at":0,"error":"","created_at":1485859669,"contact":{"id":"6317522","name":"923456812536","number":"923456812536"}},{"id":"31281984","device_id":"26965","message":"BIG WINTER CLOSING SALE! Starting from FRIDAY 30th Dec 2016. Discount upto 55%OFF on all Ladies, Gents & Kids Shoes. at All Branches of ENGLISH SHOES MULTAN. ","status":"pending","send_at":1485859669,"queued_at":0,"sent_at":0,"delivered_at":0,"expires_at":1485863269,"canceled_at":0,"failed_at":0,"received_at":0,"error":"","created_at":1485859669,"contact":{"id":"6317521","name":"923336088811","number":"923336088811"}}],"fails":[]}},"status":200}'
```

please Guide how to proceed . it seems its nested json response

Comment: start with: "$obj = json_decode($json_string)" and "var_dump($obj)".

Comment: please collaborate more . i only want to fetch "id" and device_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & Parsing a JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103607/php-parsing-a-json-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = json_decode($str);    // decode json result 
$results = [];

foreach($arr->response->result->success as $result) {
  $results[] = [
    'paramatersid' => $result->id,
    'deviceid' => $result->device_id
  ];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use this custom php code

```
<?php

$str = '{
"response": {
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "success": [{
            "id": "31281087",
            "device_id": "26965",
            "message": "BIG WINTER CLOSING SALE! Starting from FRIDAY 30th Dec 2016. Discount upto 55%OFF on all Ladies, Gents & Kids Shoes. at All Branches of ENGLISH SHOES MULTAN. ",
            "status": "pending",
            "send_at": 1485858313,
            "queued_at": 0,
            "sent_at": 0,
            "delivered_at": 0,
            "expires_at": 1485861913,
            "canceled_at": 0,
            "failed_at": 0,
            "received_at": 0,
            "error": "",
            "created_at": 1485858313,
            "contact": {
                "id": "6317513",
                "name": "0",
                "number": "0"
            }
        }],
        "fails": []
    }
},
"status": 200
```

}' ;

```
$arr = json_decode($str);    // decode json result 

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($arr);   // print $arr value parsed from json

$paramatersid = $arr->response->result->success[0]->id;    // getting id 

$divice_id = $arr->response->result->success[0]->device_id;  // getting device id 

echo $paramatersid ."<br>".$divice_id ;

?>
```

Comment: it gets only 1 item . how to fetch all using loop ?

Comment: You have json value , first decode it and after that get value as shown . You can also print decoded json like print_r($arr);  ...

Comment: i appreciate your response . but what if we need to get more items . i again updated my code and added 2 items in json . please see

Comment: You can get all the elements between ' success array at [0] index ' as like this $arr->response->result->success[0]->device_id  change device_id to message to get message ...

Comment: new code have 2 id . your code is working fine if there is 1 item in json . please have a look on code again .